# Magento 2 add Block Template in php (not XML)

Tags: layout, template, magento2.2.2

In Magento 2 one can do with XML :

```
<referenceContainer name="content.bottom">
    <block class="My\Module\Block\Index\Index" name="my.block" template="My_Module::test.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

How One can Achieve same result in php ? :
I've tried something like this:

```
$block = $resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock(
'\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template',
'my.block',
 array('template' => 'My_Module/test.phtml')
);
$resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('content.bottom')->append($block);
```

BUT it isn't working it gives the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function append() on boolean.
```

Any Ideas.Thanks.

Comment: @ Teja Bhagavan Kollepara Any Ideas?

Comment: The issue is that there is no block with the name `content.bottom`. It is a container. So when you try to get using `getBlock` it returns you `false`

Comment: @JaiminSutariya  I know I've also tried with content and yet is false. I looking to add a block not what is returning.